# Powershell - word.application doesn't work until Outlook is close

Tags: powershell, ms-word

```
$MSWord = New-Object -com word.application
$EmailOptions = $MSWord.EmailOptions
$EmailSignature = $EmailOptions.EmailSignature 
$EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature= $Username
$EmailSignature.ReplyMessageSignature= $Username
$MSWord.Quit()
```

I use that code for many months now, and it's always work until last week. Now, he got stuck on that part if Outlook s open, but still work if Outlook is close. That's a problem. Did you know if an update or something like that can have change something with Outllok ?

Thanks

Comment: Are Outlook and Word run under the same security context?

Comment: I think, yes it does